# Using redux-thunk in react-native with async dispatch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have redux-thunk set up in my react-native code.

In mapDispatchToProps I have:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
         login: (state, navigator) => dispatch({
             type: "USER",
             payload: loginFunc(state, navigator)
          }),
     }'
}
```

The login function is a firebase function that returns a promise chain that eventually returns the object I need.

However, in my reducer it looks like my payload is a promise or some funky object.
It looks like:

```
{ 
     a: someVal, 
     b: sommeOtherVal, 
     c: someMoreVal,
     ...ValsUpToI.
     i: {
       // The values I actually need show up
     }
```

This messes me up because when I try to do `payload.myValue` I get `undefined` in my redux state. I don't think it is safe to just do `payload.i` either because this is probably some `promise` or `async` issue right? That i could very well be something else later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous actions approach to execute promise based function API calls as mentioned in [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
     login: (state, navigator) => {
         return loginFunc(state, navigator).then(
             response => dispatch({
                 type: "USER",
                 payload: response
             }),
             error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
        )
     }
 }
```

That way you can call promise based function and utilize response or error correctly.